# Problems with "Bone Constraint"

Tags: bones

When i change value "Chain Length" Blender closed with no any messages. Sometimes i cant open this project (project does not open about 5 times out of 6). Once i managed set right value for "Chain Length", but when i after edit "Pole Angle" Blender closed ... When i give project to friend he dont have problems with editing this values, but what happened in my Blender? With other projects all ok.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SrIsw9kjadZ3NIdG4tVWp5LUk project.

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: I've tried it and it works well without problems, have you tried reinstalling blender?

Comment: Yes i try it, but its not help :(

Comment: Have you tried using blender .zip version found in the downloads page? You can try it and if it worked then this means there is a problem with your current python installation

Comment: I try and say you what happened, but after sleep )

Comment: Cant launch zip version, Blender cant found pythont35.dll

Comment: Hmm, after update today i not see this problem more )